# How to combine levels with some automation in R

Tags: r, levels

I have a variable in my dataset for which there are about 2000 factor levels, but many of the levels are quite similar:

```
"7" "BE Classifieds - Village Voice - Display"
"8" "Bridgevine Online"
"9" "British Columbia BNE - Group 1"
"10" "British Columbia BNE - Group 10"
"11" "British Columbia BNE - Group 11"
"12" "British Columbia BNE - Group 12"
"13" "British Columbia BNE - Group 13"
"14" "British Columbia BNE - Group 14"
"15" "British Columbia BNE - Group 2"
"16" "British Columbia BNE - Group 3"
"17" "British Columbia BNE - Group 4"
"18" "British Columbia BNE - Group 5"
"19" "British Columbia BNE - Group 6"
"20" "British Columbia BNE - Group 7"
"21" "British Columbia BNE - Group 8"
"22" "British Columbia BNE - Group 9"
"23" "buyjustenergydefault"
"24" "C2CBetaBrands"
"25" "C2CBetaElectrcity"
"26" "C2CBetaJE-ES"
"27" "CallerID Callback - Energy Savings"
"28" "Choose Energy Transfers"
"29" "Choose Energy Warm Transfers"
"30" "Clear Corporate Teletech Telesales Transfer to JE"
"31" "Clear Internet Live Transfer - TX, GA"
"32" "Clear Internet Transfer - Non-ISTA"
"33" "commenergy"
"34" "Commercial to Residential Transfer"
"35" "Coreg"
"36" "Customer Service-Energy Savings"
"37" "CW Leads - Non transfer (ISTA)"
"38" "CW Leads - Non transfer (Non-ISTA)"
"39" "D* Just Clean In-Line"
"40" "D* Transfer - Scripting Test"
"41" "Default/Unknown Program"
"42" "DirectStar Live Transfer - Retentions"
"43" "DStar (FC) Transfer"
"44" "DStar Leads - Non transfer (ISTA)"
"45" "DStar Leads - Non transfer (Non-ISTA)"
"46" "DStar Outbound Friends and Family"
"47" "Dstar to Energy Georgia Transfer"
"48" "DStar Transfer - Non-ISTA"
"49" "DStar Transfer - TX, GA"
"50" "electricdotcomwebsitedefault"
"51" "ES-AEP-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Competitors-AB"
"52" "ES-AEP-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Nonbrand-AB"
"53" "ES-AEP-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Competitor-AB"
"54" "ES-AEP-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Competitors-AB-Unspecified"
"55" "ES-AEP-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Nonbrand-AB"
"56" "es-albertaenergyprovidersca-webdefault"
"57" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Brand-GA"
"58" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Brand-NJ"
"59" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Brand-PA"
"60" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Competitors-GA"
"61" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Competitors-NJ"
"62" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Content-GA"
"63" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-NonBrand-GA"
"64" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Nonbrand-NJ"
"65" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Nonbrand-PA"
"66" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Brand-GA"
"67" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Brand-NJ"
"68" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Brand-PA"
"69" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Competitors-GA"
"70" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Competitors-GA-Unspecified"
"71" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Competitors-NJ"
"72" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Competitors-NJ-Unspecified"
"73" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Competitors-PA"
"74" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Nonbrand-GA"
"75" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Nonbrand-NJ"
"76" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-GOOG-MOBI-NT-Nonbrand-PA"
"77" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Brand-GA"
"78" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Brand-NJ"
"79" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Brand-PA"
"80" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Competitors-GA"
"81" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Competitors-NJ"
"82" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Nonbrand-GA"
"83" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Nonbrand-NJ"
"84" "ES-CEDS-HAILO-MSN-DTOP-Nonbrand-PA"
"85" "ES-EYSG-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Competitors-NY"
"86" "ES-EYSG-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Competitors-TX"
"87" "ES-EYSG-HAILO-GOOG-DTOP-Nonbrand-TX"
"88" "ES-Google-JE-AB"
"89" "es-launchpad-electriccompanycom-webdefault"
"90" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eEXST-NONE-justenergy.com-011B"
"91" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eEXST-NONE-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"92" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eGEOS[direct-energy-alberta]-NONE-albertaenergyproviders.com-DEF"
"93" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-EnergySavings.com-DEF"
"94" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-JustEnergy.com-011B"
"95" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-021nsNY"
"96" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-024nsOH"
"97" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-025nsMA"
"98" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-034nsON"
"99" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-036nsAB"
"100" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-037nsNJ"
"101" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-046nsAB"
"102" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-053AnsTX"
"103" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"104" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-086BnsTX"
"105" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-DEFnsCA"
"106" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-DEFnsIL"
"107" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-DEFnsIN"
"108" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-justenergy.com-DEFnsPA"
"109" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-newyork.justenergy.com-DEF"
"110" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-saveonenergy.com-DEF{IL}Just"
"111" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-saveonenergy.com-DEF{MA}Just"
"112" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-saveonenergy.com-DEF{NJ}Commerce"
"113" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-saveonenergy.com-DEF{PA}Commerce"
"114" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-saveonenergy.com-DEF{PA}Just"
"115" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eHOME-NONE-texas.justenergy.com-DEF"
"116" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eOTHR-NONE-EnergySavings.com-DEF"
"117" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eOTHR-NONE-JustEnergy.com-011B"
"118" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eOTHR-NONE-justenergy.com-021nsNY"
"119" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eOTHR-NONE-justenergy.com-046nsAB"
"120" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eOTHR-NONE-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"121" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eOTHR-NONE-saveonenergy.com-DEF{MA}Just"
"122" "ES-NAT-DTOP-DENT-eOTHR-NONE-saveonenergy.com-DEF{NJ}Commerce"
"123" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eEXST-OTHR-justenergy.com-024nsOH"
"124" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eEXST-OTHR-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"125" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eGEOS-OTHR-saveonenergy.com-DEF{NJ}Commerce"
"126" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eGEOS-OTHR-saveonenergy.com-DEF{PA}Commerce"
"127" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eGEOS-OTHR-saveonenergy.com-DEF{PA}Just"
"128" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-ENRG-JustEnergy.com-011B"
"129" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-ENRG-justenergy.com-046nsAB"
"130" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-ENRG-justenergy.com-DEFnsCA"
"131" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-EnergySavings.com-DEF"
"132" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-JustEnergy.com-011B"
"133" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-021nsNY"
"134" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-024nsOH"
"135" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-025nsMA"
"136" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-037nsNJ"
"137" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-046nsAB"
"138" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-054nsON"
"139" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"140" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-074nsTX"
"141" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-086BnsTX"
"142" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-DEFnsIL"
"143" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-justenergy.com-DEFnsPA"
"144" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eHOME-OTHR-newyork.justenergy.com-DEF"
"145" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-ENRG-JustEnergy.com-011B"
"146" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-EnergySavings.com-DEF"
"147" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-JustEnergy.com-011B"
"148" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-justenergy.com-021nsNY"
"149" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-justenergy.com-025nsMA"
"150" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-justenergy.com-036nsAB"
"151" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-justenergy.com-046nsAB"
"152" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"153" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-justenergy.com-DEFnsIN"
"154" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-justenergy.com-DEFnsPA"
"155" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-newyorkenergyrates.com-DEF"
"156" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-saveonenergy.com-DEF{IL}Just"
"157" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-saveonenergy.com-DEF{NJ}Commerce"
"158" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-saveonenergy.com-DEF{PA}Commerce"
"159" "ES-NAT-DTOP-REFR-eOTHR-OTHR-saveonenergy.com-DEF{TX}Just"
"160" "ES-NAT-DTOP-SENG-eEXST-BING-justenergy.com-054nsON"
"161" "ES-NAT-DTOP-SENG-eEXST-BING-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"162" "ES-NAT-DTOP-SENG-eEXST-GOOG-justenergy.com-011B"
"163" "ES-NAT-DTOP-SENG-eEXST-GOOG-justenergy.com-021nsNY"
"164" "ES-NAT-DTOP-SENG-eEXST-GOOG-justenergy.com-059nsAB"
"165" "ES-NAT-DTOP-SENG-eEXST-GOOG-justenergy.com-DEFnse
```

So I'm wondering how to combine all of the levels that start with a certain prefix, say "British Columbia BNE" - ....

I've looked into `combine.levels` and `varclus` but I don't think these are the right commands...is there a way to combine by prefix?

Comment: So need to define a very specific rule specifying which levels to collapse that a computer could understand. If combining levels that start with "British Columbia BNE" is your only requirement then that's doable, but if you're asking for a more general solution for all your levels, we need more guidance from you on what exactly can be collapsed and how that decision should be made.

Comment: Might you do something like substring the first 10 characters (or however many you think is right) and assign them to a new factor for those simplified, fewer levels?

Comment: @MrFlick if you know how to do it for British Columbia BNE then I can replicate that for the other factors like ES-CDS-HAILO

Comment: and @lawyeR that would be great if you post an example of what you are thinking

Comment: I have been looking at `grep` and `gsub` but I don't think these are what I want..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Use `idx = grep(prefix, data.frame)` to get the indices and then 
`data.frame[idx] = blah`